# Wildcard in GDAL command

Tags: wildcard, gdal

I have an archive of images and in each image folder there are 13 bands data. Now i have generated a list of all that images and want to make RGB for each of them in GDAL by using for loop. following is my command.

```
for /F "delims=" %a in (G:\list.txt) do(gdal_merge.py -separate -o 
G:%~paRGB.jp2 G:%pa_B04 G:%pa_B03 G:%pa*_B02)
```

But asterisk(*) character is not working here and returns error? What I am doing wrong? I am using GDAL 1.10 version.

Comment: So have it any suggested solution?

Comment: Anyone????????????